# Pandas Python - Grouping counts to others

Tags: python, pandas

I am conducting data analysis for a project using python and pandas where I have the following data:

The numbers are the count.

```
USA: 5000
Canada: 7000
UK: 6000
France: 6500
Spain: 4000
Japan: 5
China: 7
Hong Kong: 10
Taiwan: 6
New Zealand: 8
South Africa: 11
```

My task is to make a pie chart that represent the count.

`df['Country'].value_counts().plot.pie()`

What I will get is a pie chart, but I would like to combined the countries with smaller counts and put them into a category like other.

How can I do that?

Comment: How small is small ?

Comment: I want to group Japan, China, Hong Kong, Taiwan, NZL, and South Africa and show them as other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `np.where` setting the boundary , then `groupby` + `sum` , notice here I am using [`pandas.Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.htmlis)

```
s=df['Country'].value_counts()
s.groupby(np.where(s>=4000,s.index,'other')).sum()#.plot.pie()
Out[64]: 
Canada    7000
France    6500
Spain     4000
UK        6000
USA       5000
other       47
```